# Как избежать повторяющихся чисел в рекурсии Python

Tags: python, рекурсия, числа-фибоначчи

есть стандартный цикл Фибоначчи записанный следующим кодом с помощью рекурсии но в данном коде вычисление повторяются, как избежать повторных вычислений

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n in (1, 2):
        return 1
    if n in (3,):
        print(3,)

    return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)


print(fibonacci(10))
```

Comment: как вариант можете воспользоваться мемоизацией.

Comment: может я чего-то недопонимаю... куда делся 0 из ряда Фибоначчи и вроде без строк "if n in (3,): print(3,)" все прекрасно работает)

Comment: Проще всего использовать `lru_cache`, ну или самостоятельно сохранять результаты в словарь.

Comment: а как для этой функции реализовать запись в словарь посмотрел справки и документацию ничего не подходит